# Any way to stop emacs from auto-insterting EOF when angle brackets are typed?

Tags: bash, emacs

When emacs is in shell script mode, it automatically adds matching EOF tags to my buffer whenever I type `<<` and it is not the start of the line, quoted, or escaped.

I assume this is a shortcut for heredocs, but it makes it a pain to use the triple angle bracket for bash herestrings, as in `bc <<< "some_command"` (it's a bash operator that has the same effect as piping through echo (e.g., `echo "some_command" | bc`))

In emacs, when I try to type the above line, as soon as I make it to `bc <<`, emacs automatically inserts EOFs, changing my buffer to

```
bc <<EOF

EOF
```

Is there any way to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is answered here: [emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5336](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5336). Namely, it's caused by `sh-electric-here-document-mode`, which you can disable with a hook like so:

```
(add-hook 'sh-mode-hook (lambda () (sh-electric-here-document-mode -1)))
```